# Conflict while mapping results in struts.xml

Tags: java, struts2

I have 3 methods defined in **MyBdbSearch** class and same have been mapped in struts.xml as follows.

**struts.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">    

        <action name="bdbSearch" 
                class="com.bdb.MyBdbSearchAction"
                method="showSearchPage">
              <result name="okBdbSearchPage">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
        </action>

         <action name="bdbSearch" 
                class="com.bdb.MyBdbSearchAction"
                method="search">
              <result name="okBdbSearch">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="bdbSearch" 
                class="com.bdb.MyBdbSearchAction"
                method="getNextResults">
              <result name="okBdbSearch">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
        </action>
     </package>
</struts>
```

**MyBdbSearchAction.java**

```
public class MyBdbSearchAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{    

@Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.request = request;
    }



    public String showSearchPage(){

        //some initialization code
        return "okBdbSearchPage";
    }

public String search(){

        //some code
        return "okBdbSearch";
    }

public String getNextResults(){

    //some code
    return "okBdbSearch";
}
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<body>
    <s:url id="searchUrl" action="/bdbSearch" method="showSearchPage"></s:url>
    <s:a href="%{searchUrl}">
        <h4>search</h4>
    </s:a>
</body>
</html>
```

When only one method (showSearchPage) is configured in xml file, app works fine. But if all the 3 methods are configured as above, it throws below error.

***No result defined for actions com.bdb.MyBdbSearchAction and result okBdbSearchPage***

Why such weird behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change .xml file it as below:

```
<struts>
<include file="struts-default.xml"/>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">    

    <action name="bdbSearch" class="com.bdb.MyBdbSearchAction">
          <result name="okBdbSearchPage">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
          <result name="okBdbSearch">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
          <result name="okBdbSearch">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
    </action>
 </package>
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me improve my understanding about how results/actions are mapped in Struts2

Comment: you are welcome my friend.